# Submitting multiple email addresses but only one email gets sent

Tags: javascript, php, email, mysqli

I want to send the same email to several recipients, my code is as followed:

My contact.php so I can edit what I want the message and the subject to be in my website

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $to = $_POST['email'];
      $from = "my_email@gmail.com";
      $subject = $_POST['subject'];
      $message = $_POST['message'];

      $headers = "From:" . $from;
      mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
      echo "Email enviado";
      }
?>
```

My index.php, the dbh.php is the connection to the database.

```
<?php
    include_once 'dbh.php';  
    include_once 'contact.php';  
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
    body {
        background-image: url("http://mapinstitute.org/data/wallpapers/110/im58522201.jpg");
    }

    .mail {
        width:355px;
        height:550px;
        font-size:25px;
        text-align:center;
        color:white;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT Nome,EmailGeral FROM escolas;";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            echo "<select name='Nome' multiple='multiple'>";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
               echo "<option value='" . $row['Nome'] ."'>" . $row['Nome'] ."</option>";
               "<option value='" . $row['EmailGeral'] ."'>" . $row['EmailGeral'] ."</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";
        ?>

        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="mail">
            <form action="" method="post">
            <button type="button" onclick="emailNext();">Add Email</button>
            <div id="addEmail"></div>

            <script>

            function emailNext() {
            var nextEmail, inside_where;
            nextEmail = document.createElement('input');
            nextEmail.type = 'text';
            nextEmail.name = 'email';
            nextEmail.className = 'class_for_styling';
            nextEmail.style.display = 'block';
            nextEmail.placeholder = 'Insert your Email';
            inside_where = document.getElementById('addEmail');
            inside_where.appendChild(nextEmail);
            return false;
            }

            </script>

            Subject:<br><textarea rows="1" name="subject" cols="30"></textarea><br>
            Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I execute my code it only sends to the last email submitted. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
nextEmail.name = 'email[]';
```

With:

```
$to = implode(',', $_POST['email']);
```

Comment: Note that you are emailing to the addresses posted in the form and not to those in the database.